# running basic http server using node.js on Mac

Tags: node.js, macos

I'm new to node.js and was trying to run the following training example for setting up a basic http server on my mac (OS X Yosemite 10.10.3):

```
var http = require("http");



http.createServer(function (request, response) {

request.on("end", function () {

    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });

    response.end('Hello HTTP!');
});

}).listen(8080);
```

I get the following error when executing the code:

> $ node http.js events.js:85
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>               ^ Error: listen EADDRINUSE
>       at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
>       at Server._listen2 (net.js:1156:14)
>       at listen (net.js:1182:10)
>       at Server.listen (net.js:1267:5)
>       at Object. (/Users/sumankalyan/WebstormProjects/Node-Server/http.js:25:4)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)

Not sure if this is a localhost config issue or something else.  Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Another application is using the port 8080. You can run

```
lsof -i :8080
```

to see what it is. You can also just try another port.

Comment: Thanks. That solved the problem. I tried another port and it seemed to work fine.